# Why there is no "View Output" button for the command "v.to.points" in Grass plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, point, line

How do i get or where do i get my output vector point layer after i run the command v.to.points to my vector line layer?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using and for which platform (e.g. Windows, Mac...)?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in my question only.. I am using QGIS 2.10.1 and I want to create points along the line layer. I got the line layer from polygon layer using Vector-Geometry tools-Polygons to lines. Then I imported the layer to Grass and tried to generate points along the lines using v.to.points. The command runs well but I cannot load the map into TOC.

Comment: No worries and thanks for mentioning :). QGIS 2.10.1 seems to have this option missing as described in my post.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that a number of tools in QGIS 2.10.1 with GRASS 6.4.3 do not have the *"View output"* option, although some do.

However, in **QGIS 2.12**, the `v.to.points` tool **does** have this option:

[image: GRASS in QGIS 2.12]

Perhaps you could consider upgrading :)

Comment: Thx Joseph! Can't keep up with the speed of QGIS.. I quite like this software :)

Comment: Most welcome buddy! Yeah, they release major updates about [every four months](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#road-map) but it just gets more and more powerful each time :)

Comment: Yes,, but do you know if there is a way to load the vector layer in TOC in QGIS 2.10.1? I have done this before and have loaded the resulting vector layer but have forgot and somehow don't remember it now.. :(

Comment: I only ever used this tool from the **Processing Toolbox** which loads the layer into the ToC, haven't used it through GRASS though, sorry!